# AWS how to create subdomain and access them from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm starting to get confused by reading and seeing videos on the internet.
My **EC2 maven** and **docker instances** are **running** and I can **access** them with the public address I have defined.

I've made the request for the ssl certificate for the domain name `xxx.io`
I want to **create** two **subdomains** `maven.xx.io` and `docker.xx.io` to be able to **access them** from **outside** in https.

However the **maven** instance is **listening** on port **8081** and the **docker** instance on **8082**.

Do I have to create a cluster ?

How can I do for the ports ?

[architecture design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7GWf.png)

Comment: You can install nginx reverse proxy on those EC2 instances which would listen on port 443 (https) and proxy requests to maven and docker ports. Refer : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: there is no way to do it from AWS directly ?

Comment: you can use load balancer before your EC2 instances. Load balancer would listen on port 443 and forward for instance port that you need.